# Connection between superconductivity and breaking of $U(1)$ symmetry in superconductors

Tags: schroedinger-equation, superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate, mean-field-theory

$\newcommand{\Ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$Suppose I have a total Hamiltonian $H = H_0 + V$ given by the usual kinetic term $$H_0 = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \sum_{\mathbf{k}, \sigma = \uparrow, \downarrow} \; \mathbf{k}^2 c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{k} \sigma}c_{\mathbf{k} \sigma}$$ and an interaction $$V = -g \int d^3 \mathbf{x} \; \psi^{\dagger}_{\downarrow} \left( \mathbf{x} \right) \psi^{\dagger}_{\uparrow} \left( \mathbf{x} \right) \psi_{\uparrow} \left( \mathbf{x} \right) \psi_{\downarrow} \left( \mathbf{x} \right) ,$$ with $ g > 0$.

Let us assume that we are interested in the zero-temperature case, that is we are dealing with ground state properties only. Since the Hamiltonian conserves the number of particles we can further assume that we are interested in states with a fixed number of particles $N$. After all we can imagine that in a real metal the number of electrons is (in an ideal case) fixed at all times.

Of course we can solve the Hartree-Fock (HF) equation to find the best particle-number conserving mean-field solution $\Ket{0}$.

If we could solve the full Schrodinger equation we would get the *exact* ground state $\Ket{GS}$, which could be written as a linear combination of particle-hole excitations over the HF solution. That is, in a very schematic way,

\begin{equation} \tag{1}
\Ket{GS} = \Ket{0} + \Ket{1 \text{particle} - 1 \text{hole}} + \Ket{2 \text{particle} - 2 \text{hole}} + ...
\end{equation}

This solution contains all pairing information and it is the best description of a system at zero temperature governed by the Hamiltonian $H$. In particular it is the best possible way of studying superconductivity effects at $T = 0$, because we would know the exact solution of the system with the correct, fixed, number of electrons.

Since this is the best description of superfluidity, while HF is effectively a non-description of superfluidity, *why* does breaking the particle-number symmetry in BCS provide a better mean-field approximation of $(1)$? I understand that a larger variational space can provide lower energy solutions, but why does BCS capture the pairing features that are contained in $(1)$ so well? Is there an intuitive or a mathematical way (both would be even better) to see this?

Comment: Steven Weinberg has a famous paper about this: https://academic.oup.com/ptps/article/doi/10.1143/PTPS.86.43/1885987

Comment: @Andrew Thank you, I just had the time to give a look at Weinberg's argument. From what I was able to understand he argues that the ground state of the Hamiltonian breaks particle-number symmetry. However I do not really understand this point because the ground state I have written has a definite number of particles. The way I tried to make sense of it is by assuming that the ground state is degenerate, with many different particle-number non-conserving states with the same energy. Diagonalizing H we just happen to find a linear combination of them that satisfies particle-number conservation.

Comment: @Andrew Is my interpretation correct? If it is then is it correct to say that when we are solving the BCS equation we are just approximating one of these states with an ansatz with the correct (broken) symmetry, hence allowing us to capture the physics of these states more precisely?

Comment: I'm just an (ex) particle/cosmology theorist, so I don't know much about condensed matter :) What I understand Weinberg's point to be, is that the important fact from which most of the precisely known properties of superconductors follows, is that the effective low energy theory has a spontaneously broken $U(1)$ gauge symmetry, rather than from detailed microphysical models.